# how to replace multiple text line with new text

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, ubuntu-18.04

I have:

```
SIESTA_ARCH = unknown
CC = gcc
FPP = $(FC) -E -P -x c 
FC = gfortran
```

and I want to replace this by

```
SIESTA_ARCH = amd64 (x86_64) 
CC = mpicc 
FPP = $(FC) -E -P -x c 
FC = mpif90
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do we have to understand that the lines you want to process litterally contain the string "First line", etc... ?

Comment: @Pierre François  I edited my question again

Comment: Thank you, but next time please, do not include screenshots which we can't copy/paste for testing. This time, I will edit the question for you.

Comment: Do you want a compendium of all the ways you could do this, or do you simply want one that works?  Does it have to be treated as a block, or should (could) it be treated as 3 different single-line changes to be applied in one edit operation?  You could use `sed`, `awk`, `perl`, `python`, `ruby` for the task; any of them would do so with aplomb.  With a bit more effort, there are other options too — `ed`, `ex` for example.  Should the code validate that the line is as you expect, or should it simply look for the markers (up to the equals sign) and replace that line with the desired output?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 I want substitute it all together

Comment: Does that mean there will be instances of e.g. `CC = gcc` elsewhere in the file that you don't want to modify? You only want to modify it if it appears within this specific block?

Comment: @pallgeuer yes, I only want to modify it if it appears within this specific block

Answer (score 1):

I guess next solution is working for you (**edited solution** according to answers of the PO):

**script.sed**

```
#!/bin/sed -f

/^SIESTA_ARCH = unknown/,/^FC =/{
  s/^SIESTA_ARCH =.*/SIESTA_ARCH = amd64 (x86_64)/
  s/^CC =.*/CC = mpicc/
  s/^FC =.*/FC = mpif90/
}
```

Invoke as `./script.sed Makefile` to see the results on the standard output or as  `./script.sed -i Makefile` to update the file `Makefile`.

This solution will change all the occurences of `SIESTA_ARCH = unknown` and the next line block until a line beginning with `FC =` into the new values.

Comment: yes in my makefile many 'CC' and 'FC' I just want to change specific.

Comment: In the case you don't want to change all the lines starting with `CC =`, please edit your question to specify in which case you have to update these lines. For example: for all the occurences of `SIESTA_ARCH = unknown` change this line in `SIESTA_ARCH = amd64 (x86_64)` **and** in the 3 (or 4, whatever) lines immediately after, change `CC = ...` into `CC = mpicc` and `FP = ...` into `FC = mpif90`. In function of your answer, I will post the solution.

Comment: I updated my code to work only on blocks, as you requested in your comments. Editing your question in order to clarify this would be a good idea. I suggest you also to add some input that must not be changed in order to check if the proposed solutions are working correctly.

Comment: If you update your question, please explain how you define a block. For instance a set of lines starting with `SIESTA_ARCH = unknown` and stopping after a line beginning with `FC =`

Answer (score 0):

In bash you can define a function like this (just execute this one-liner in a terminal or script):

```
function repl() { FIND="$2" REPLACE="$3" ruby -p -i -e "gsub(ENV['FIND'], ENV['REPLACE'])" "$1"; }
```

Then you can replace whatever literal strings you want in whatever file, e.g.:

```
repl ~/Code/Makefile 'SIESTA_ARCH = unknown' 'SIESTA_ARCH = amd64 (x86_64)'
repl ~/Code/Makefile 'CC = gcc' 'CC = mpicc'
repl ~/Code/Makefile 'FC = gfortran' 'FC = mpif90'
```

Note that this will replace all occurrences of such strings in the specified file.

Comment: That presumes the poster has `ruby` installed, and knows how to (make) use (of) it.

Comment: @ Roadowl No I don't know

Comment: It's an option at least, and in many cases `ruby` will already be available without the user explicitly having to install anything and you can just check for the existence using `ruby --version`. There's not more you need to know about `ruby` then to make use of it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have `ed`

```
cat script.ed
```

```
H
g/^\(SIESTA_ARCH =\)\(.\+\)$/s//\1 amd64 (x86_64)/
g/^\(CC =\)\(.\+\)$/s//\1 mpicc/
,p
Q
```

Using the script against your file.

```
ed -s Makefile < script.ed
```

Output

```
SIESTA_ARCH = amd64 (x86_64)
CC = mpicc
FPP = $(FC) -E -P -x c
FC = gfortran
```

Now change `,p Q` to `w` and `q` To edit the file in-place.

```
H
g/^\(SIESTA_ARCH =\)\(.\+\)$/s//\1 amd64 (x86_64)/
g/^\(CC =\)\(.\+\)$/s//\1 mpicc/
w
q
```

```
ed -s Makefile < script.ed
```

Comment: This solution will change all the occurences of `CC =`. It is not what the PO wants; he wants only to change the occurence of `CC = ` in the block following `SIESTA_ARCH =  unknown`, as far as I understand.